Help with troubleshooting 4017 issues
I'm trying to troubleshoot a 555-4017 LED chaser circuit, where multiple LEDs are on in the initial state, and the clock signal from the 555 doesn't seem to do anything.
I've got some general questions that I think would help my debugging:

Should pin 13/15 (enable/reset) be directly connected to ground? Because I've also seen schematics that put like a 100k resistor in between to catch power spikes.
Should all pins of the 4017 be connected? Can I just hook up the first 2 or 3 pins of the cycle to see if it its actually stepping?
Will any signal of a 555 output work for the clock? Does it matter if there's a LED/resistor on there as well for debugging? Maybe I'll get an oscillator later on to check the frequency/shape of the output..
Can I trigger the clock manually, without the 555? By for example connecting to pin to V+ for a moment?

Thanks for any advice!
edit: here's one of the many example circuits that I've tried to create. This one sends the non-used pins directly to ground.


Oli - Hi, Where exactly did the image come from? I know there's a watermark, but to comply with the site rule on referencing, specific details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. || If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage / PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then give full details of the source e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

The 4017 uses 5 flip-flops to form a Johnson counter to simplify decoding, hence there are \$2^5 - 10\$ = 22 illegal states. It can power up in any state. A reset pulse will force it to the '0' state or it will eventually right itself after some clock pulses.
There is no need to connect all the pins on a CMOS chip, however at a minimum you should connect the two power pins and every input (unless there's something specific in the datasheet that tells you that there is a pullup or pulldown on the chip, and that's not the case with the 4017). Any or all outputs can be left open.
In the case of the 4017 you need to connect the clock, clock inhibit and reset pins (along with Vdd and GND). You can ground the reset and clock inhibit pins directly (no need for a resistor).
Any input has to go from 0.3 * Vdd (or lower) to 0.7 * Vdd (or higher) to be a valid CMOS logic level. If your 555 output does that (and it should) then the counter should count.
Whilst you could add a pulldown resistor (say 10kΩ between the input and ground) to the clock input and momentarily brush the wire to the clock input against Vdd, the number of counts you get would appear rather random. The counter (even at 5V) can count at several MHz and your contact is likely to have a bunch of noise that will be interpreted as counts. A mechanical switch will have a similar problem. That's why we talk about "debouncing" the input.
Remember, leaving an input open on a CMOS chip such as this one does not make the input '0', it makes it "unknown". It can drift from '0' to '1', back and forth at your mains frequency or pick up other noise.

OK, so it's the voltage that makes a valid signal, and the current doesnt really matter. Thanks for the explanation

For this part of the question:

Should pin 13/15 (enable/reset) be directly connected to ground?


Pin 13 CLOCK INHIBIT can be directly connected to ground. This is because for the LED chaser there is no need to inhibit the clock.
Pin 15 RESET should be pulsed high at power up to place the CD4017 5 flip-flops into a legal initial state, as already mentioned in the other answer. See "Power On Reset" on CD4026 IC and Question about capacitor and resistor in "power on reset circuit" for how a resistor and capacitor can be used to provide an active high power on reset pulse.


I know it's not quite the same circuit, but you can find a very similar one in this article along with a ton of information.
The datasheet for the CD4017 from TI is here. and I note on page 3 there is a table of limits. Under "Output Low (sink) Current" at 25C the maximum is 6.8mA and in the other table above it says "DC input current, any one input +/- 10ma". Similarly there is a graph (fig 6)showing a maximum of about 7.5mA sink current with a 10V supply.
As far as I can see the 330ohm resistor, common to all the LEDs, would allow about 25mA through the selected LED with a 9V supply., well in excess of the datasheet maxima. Your setup might have overloaded the output circuits of the 4017.
Regarding the other differences between your circuit and that in the article. Nice to see you've included the 10nF capacitor from Pin 5 to ground on the 555. The pins you've grounded are the same and appear to be correct for the unused inputs. I would query the 100K potentiometer VR1 as it is nearly 2 orders of magnitude greater than R2, 10K ohms is more then big enough.
